# Child divs not wrapping to stay inside parent

Tags: html, css

Take a look at this fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/mstwp/

The html is:

```
<div id="parent" style="width: 150px; display: inline-block; white-space: nowrap">

    <div id="one" class="kids">
        <span>Hi</span>
    </div>

    <div id="two" class="kids">
        <span>Bob like to play on his violin</span>
    </div>

</div>
```

with CSS:

```
#parent {
    background-color: #aaaaaa
}
#one {
    background-color: #ff0000
}

#two {
    background-color: #00ff00
}

.kids {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 2px;
    white-space: normal;
}
```

How can I make div #two wrap earlier so that I can keep both child divs inside the parent div?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just remove the width attached to the parent. It forces the parent div to increase its height to accomodate the content in the div `#two`. SO keep the parent div as such:

```
<div id="parent" style="display: inline-block; white-space: nowrap">
```

And this should do the trick for you.

Alternately, you could add a min-height to the parent div so that it automatically accomodates its width based on the content inside its child. So your parent div could look like this:

```
<div id="parent" style="min-width: 150px; display: inline-block; white-space: nowrap">
```

Hope this helps!!!

EDIT: Your child divs already wraps inside the parent div. This is 'revealed' when you add a small width to one of the child div named `two`.

See that here : http://jsfiddle.net/K2xn5/

If you want you div `two` to wrap within the `parent` div, then there's no point in attaching a fixed width to the `parent`. Instead, you will need to provide a fixed width to the div named `two`. This would then occupy the space AS DEFINED by the content. Your `parent` div would then just keep expanding based on the size of its children, in this case, div `one` and `two`.

Check out these fiddles :

Fixed width to child, no width to the parent:  http://jsfiddle.net/K2xn5/1/

Child div wrapping itself based on the size of its content: http://jsfiddle.net/K2xn5/2/ and http://jsfiddle.net/K2xn5/3/

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: If I remove the width from the parent, then it sizes the parent to fit everything without wrapping. That's not what I want.

Comment: @Erik Please see the edit. I guess this should solve your problem.

Comment: Okay, I can use this to change my approach to make it work. I had assumed that the child div would wrap when its size, plus its siblings size matched the parents size. But it looks like it wraps when its size is 100% of the parent size. I can set % widths on the children so that they both stay inside the parent when the text wraps.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like both child divs are being wrapped correctly? They're both inside the gray 150px parent box.

BTW this short tutorial helped me a lot with my CSS learning.

http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/

Comment: Maybe it depends on your font size. What browser are you using? I'm using chrome and the green child extends farther than the grey parent.